# Passing a parameter to MSTests using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, conditional-statements, mstest, tfsbuild

I've got an issue that was wondering if could be solved in a particular way.

I would like to be able to pass a parameter or set some kind of variable in an MSBuild script that will be run on a TeamBuild server.

This parameter would be used as a condition in the setup of a TestFixture in MSTest to decided which concrete implementation of a class to be used. It would be a mock version when running on the build server, and a reference to a physical asset when running on a developer machine.

Is this easily possible? I could set an environment variable but would prefer if there was something specific in MSTest and MSBuild that could be used.

Comment: I'm interested this question in the context of deployment package validation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844270/how-to-validate-deployment-packages-created-by-msbuild-preferably-using-mstest). We all know if you passing parameters to the test fixture, it is not a unit test. However, it is also valuable to automate tests at levels above unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a xUnit guideline, tests should **not** take in parameters. They should just run without someone having to configure them.

```
public void TestMethodName()
```

Your need seems to be more towards [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). For which frameworks like [Spring.Net](http://www.springframework.net/) are a better fit.

**Update:**
From your comment, it seems all you require is a switch similar to a #define BUILD. Try Conditional Compilation symbols (Project Settings>Build) coupled with a ReplaceCollaboratorsForBuildServer method that is decorated with the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) and called at the end of your testFixture Setup method.

Comment: We're using Unity, but we're wanting to avoid having to use elaborate configuration files to set up the tests, hence why one piece of information stating that it was running on a build server which could be accessed from code would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this that I have found is to write configuration files. There are MsBuild community tasks that make this possible.